# Does using .reset() on a std::shared_ptr delete all instances

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, shared-memory, shared-ptr

I'm new to shared_ptr's and I'm trying to figure out the exact functionality of the .reset() function.

```
#include <memory>
#include <stdio>

using namespace std;
class SomeClass{};

int main() 
{
   shared_ptr<SomeClass> sp (nullptr);

   //do some stuff, sp now has 10 co-owners

   cout << sp.use_count << endl;
   sp.reset();
   cout << sp.use_count << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Would output

```
10
0
```

So since I used the reset function are all instances deleted from memory? As in, have I just eliminated any possible memory leaks with sp? Obviously this was a toy example that I quickly made up, sorry if it has any errors.

Follow up situation:

```
shared_ptr<SomeClass> returnThis() {
    shared_ptr<SomeClass> someObject(new SomeClass(/*default constructor for example*/) );
    return someObject;
}
```

somehere in main:

```
shared_ptr<SomeClass> mainObject;
mainObject = returnThis();
```

Does mainObject have a use count of 2 because someObject was created in a function but never cleared? Or is it one and the clean-up is done automatically when returning the value?

Comment: Whoops!  If you want to ask a follow-up question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page.  The short story is that `shared_ptr` exists to automatically handle all of these things, so when the *last* shared pointer leaves scope, the object is destroyed.

Comment: [Equivalent to shared_ptr().swap(*this);](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When you use `.reset()`, you are eliminating *one* owner of the pointer, but all of the other owners are still around.  Here is an example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>

class Test { public: ~Test() { std::puts("Test destroyed."); } };

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Test> p = std::make_shared<Test>();
    std::shared_ptr<Test> q = p;
    std::puts("p.reset()...");
    p.reset();
    std::puts("q.reset()...");
    q.reset();
    std::puts("done");
    return 0;
}
```

The program output:

```
p.reset()...
q.reset()...
Test destroyed.
done
```

Note that `p` and `q` are both owners of the object, and once both `p` and `q` are reset, **then** the instance is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As a follow up question, say I have a function that's return type is a std::shared_ptr but the shared_ptr that I'm returning was created inside that function, will returning the shared_ptr automatically decrement its use_count by 1? I'll post a follow up example above.

Answer (score 19):

No.

The whole purpose of `shared_ptr` is that you cannot delete it from one place if someone is using it in another. `shared_ptr::reset()` just decreases `use_count` by one and replaces its object by `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2):

The .reset() method only applies to the object it's called upon.

It just replaces the pointer that variable is holding.